# Image in a cell shows above textLabel and detailTextLabel but under accessory view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a UIImageView as a subview in a UITableViewCell. I wish it to be above everything in the cell (thus, user cannot see anything that is covered by this imageView). However, it only covers the textLabel and the detailTextLabel, but not the accessoryView. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks a lot.

---

Here's some code:
When initializing the cell, I have

```
[cell setAccessoryView:rangeIndicatorView];
```

And when I add an imageView on top of it,

```
-(void) animateSwipeOnCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell {
    UIImageView *swipeImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe_arrow.png"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:swipeImg];
    [swipeImg setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x - cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.origin.y, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0.3
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         [swipeImg setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x + cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.origin.y, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [swipeImg removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

}
```

Comment: Add the image view to the cell's `contentView`, not directly to the cell.

Comment: Do you have some code for us?

Comment: @rmaddy doesn't work for me. The imageView is still under accessoryView

Comment: @HermannKlecker code is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make it work by adding the image directly to the UITableViewCell, so here's an alternative, by putting the view directly on the UITableView:

```
- (void)animateSwipeOnTableView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImageView *swipeImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe_arrow.png"]];
    CGRect tableViewRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView addSubview:swipeImg];

    [swipeImg setFrame:CGRectMake(tableViewRect.origin.x - tableViewRect.size.width, tableViewRect.origin.y, tableViewRect.size.width, tableViewRect.size.height)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0.3
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         [swipeImg setFrame:CGRectMake(tableViewRect.origin.x + tableViewRect.size.width, tableViewRect.origin.y, tableViewRect.size.width, tableViewRect.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [swipeImg removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: I think this animation won't move as the cell moves when a user scrolls during an animation

Comment: No, I have actually tried that and it works just fine. You can scroll, since the UITablleView is a subclass of UIScrollView, the content being animated moves along as well.